# Amazon SNS configuration for Topics for iPhone/APNs integration

Tags: apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I am trying to configure Amazon's SNS service to communicate to the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) and can not figure out what Amazon want's for the Topic.

According to Apple: A topic is the bundle ID associated with one of your apps.  (as referenced here: [IOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

And i forgot where i looked this up originally but the bundle ID for my app in xCode is like a url in reverse.  so for me it is "com.m2.velexo2" and i have created provisioning profiles to go with this.

Now on AWS in the SNS section there is a place where i can create new topics (right under where it says SNS Home)  To create a topic i need two fields "Topic Name" and "Display Name".

If i put my bundle id in the Topic Name field it says "Topic Name contains invalid characters. Must contain only alphanumeric characters, hyphen (-), and underscore (_)."

If i put it in the other field then it says "Topic display name cannot exceed 10 characters in length"

I don't get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only stuff you should need to fill out to get the APNS stuff set up in SNS.

[image: AWS Create Screen]

Creating a new topic does not have anything to do with communication the with between SNS and APNS it's more of a way to group app users so that you can send push notifications to a bunch of different devices without having to send a notification to each individual user.

The documentation on this is pretty good on Amazons website:
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html

Hope this helps,

Comment: This looks correct, however i have no idea because i completely gave up on using Amazon SNS service and ended up doing a manual connection to the APNs.  Here is another question where i show the code how this is done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065245/apple-push-notification-service-connects-but-no-notification-is-recieved/37076379#37076379